# Accessibility: Shortcuts for color inversion + mousewheel for zoom

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, accessibility

I have been using macOS for the longest part of my live, simply because it had much better accessibility options than either Linux or Windows XP at that time - and even going forward, it took until Windows 10 for that to become an option. But periodically, I will look at Linux and wonder if there is a proper way to establish my workflow under Linux. And since I kinda like the prospect of Ubuntu 20.04, I decided to get back into it by installing 18.04 LTS through Windows Hyper-V to test it out.

I was happy to see that zooming in and out was now available as a shortcut and the "follow mouse" mode was available as well.

Unfortunately, this is where the positives end, and why I came here to ask for advice.

I would like to:

- Be able to adjust zoom levels by using my mouse wheel, since it's usually faster than tapping keys on my keyboard.
- Be able to turn on or off color inversion through a shortcut.

From what I know, 18.04 is based on GNOME - so, there should be an option to do that in other GNOME-based distros too. I would guess that Compiz has similar features as well, but that would be something for another question.

When heading into Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard, I can only seem to adjust the zoom in and zoom out via keyboard shortcuts - and they do not allow me to assign my mousewheel with it too, unfortunately. Color inverse is not even present in that menu at all. Using `xcalib -a -i` did not do anything when I tried it out unfortunately.

So, any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

I found your post while looking for a way to zoom using mouse-wheel. Still searching.

But there is a way to get the invert-color with a shortcut.
Use gnome-shell extensions. Invert-window-color works and has Super-I as default shortcut.

[Invert Window Color](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1041/invert-window-color/)

Comment: Hey. Don't know if you are still searching, but [Wayfire](https://github.com/WayfireWM/wayfire) has desktop and individual window zoom and you can try it out in Garuda Linux. It works pretty well and is what I use on my secondary maschine now. Just...don't try to use NVIDIA drivers if you value your time and stick to Nuveaou. ;)